# Alternative to WCF Duplex Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am sorry if ths has been handled earlier. I have been searching for a while.

I have a requirement which involves the following:
1.  A code kicks off every month.
2.  It needs to call a WCF Service to start off some work.
3.  Then it needs to keep polling a service every 5 minutes to check if the task is complete.
4.  Once complete the code moves on. I cannot execute any code till the WCF Service has returned.
I do not want to use WCF duplex binding. This is a code running in Windows service.

I was wondering what is the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Have you looked into using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) ?  It works great for web apps and I believe you can use it with WCF services and Windows Services.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use SignalIR as its not part of out company's accepted solution

Comment: Instead of polling, when the WCF service completes, can it make a call back to the Windows service via some abstracted WCF service on that machine? [Here are some ideas](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/688264/Calling-WCF-service-from-another-WCF-service)

Answer (score 0):

Use a message queue system. If that is not part of the company's "accepted solutions", tell them why you need it and how it makes life easier - so that it can be included! Like Jason pointed out SignalR can also be an option here.

If you want a "better" answer you need to improve your question: what does bullet 1 mean? "Kicks off"...?